# I'm preparing data for multi-state modelling but I get this error: Error in hlpsrt[, 1] - hlpsrt[, 2] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: database, plot, state, modeling, survival

I want to perform a **multi-state analysis** in order to study the disease progress of several subjects. I want to create a **multi-state model** and **plot the transition probabilities**.

However, when I use *msprep* function of R `mstate` package to transform data from wide to long format, I get this error:

**Error in hlpsrt[, 1] - hlpsrt[, 2] :
non-numeric argument to binary operator**

Does anyone know the meaning of hlpsrt | how to solve this error?

There is very little information about the use of `mstate` package. TT

Thank you very much for your help !

EI_Stats  :)

Comment: @El_Stats, did you manage to find out?